# Non UI examples for Csound on Android

Tags: android, csound

I've looked at the examples that come with Csound for android but I want to call it without using the UI widgets that all the examples seem to be about.

I know about how to load up an instrument but how do I ask it to play a note of a specified frequency?

Do I use sendscore?

Cheers.

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure about the Android API to Csound, but if there's a function called sendscore it sounds like the right one. You probably need to send a string like:

```
i 1 0 10
```

(This means turn on instrument 1 now (time=0) for 10 seconds)
You may want to use more values if your instrument is set up for it (using what are called p-fields in Csound).

The C API functions for this are:

```
PUBLIC int  csoundScoreEvent (CSOUND *, char type, const MYFLT *pFields, long numFields)
PUBLIC int  csoundReadScore (CSOUND *csound, const char *str)
```

Check out:

http://csound.github.io/docs/api/group__CONTROLEVENTS.html
http://csound.github.io/docs/api/group__SCOREHANDLING.html